# Proving there aren't any more subgroups for $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I'm currently doing an exercise to find all the subgroups of $S_3$, with a hint given that there are exactly $6$ and then to prove that no more subgroups exist. Take $$() \equiv e, (12) \equiv x, (13) \equiv y, (23) \equiv z, (123) \equiv \alpha, (132) \equiv \beta$$ Then for the subgroups we have:

As with any group we have the group itself $S_3$ and the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$. Now by inspection of the multiplication table we have $\{e, \alpha, \beta\}, \{e, x\}, \{e, y\}, \{e, z\}$ These are all subgroups because they fulfill the requirements for a subgroup. Namely that they are closed under products and inverses.

---

Now, I want to show that no more subgroups can exist. I was going to go about showing this by showing that each possible permutation (a set with any elements except the identity, a set with only transpositions but more than $1$ transposition, etc...) doesn't fulfill the requirements above. This is obviously quite tedious and I'm wondering if there's a more systematic way to show this.

**For Context:** The only facts we have been presented with thus far about the existence of subgroups have been for $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z_n}$. We have not encountered the theorem that states that for a finite group, the order of any subgroup must divide the order of the group. Which we can see here since $\lvert S_3 \rvert = 6$ and the only positive integers which divide $6$ are $1$, $2$, $3$ and $6$, which are the orders of the subgroups listed. So we aren't "allowed" to use that reasoning.

Comment: You could show:(1) if it contains a 2-cycle and *any* other nonidentity element then it is the whole group, and (2) if it contains a 3-cycle and any nonidetity element other than the inverse of that 3-cycle then it is the whole group. You may be able to do this by naming the specific 2 and 3 cycles say $(ab)$ and $(abc)$ and being careful about letters for the other permutation mentioned. That would save you having to do every 2 cycle and every 3-cycle.

Comment: The number of members of a subgroup of a finite group of $n$ members is a divisor of $n$. So if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $S_3$ with more than 1 member then $H$ has exactly 2 or 3 members, so $H=\{e,x\}$ where $e=x^2\ne x,$ or $H=\{e,x,x^2\}$ where $( x\ne e\ne x^2\land x^3=e)$ because these are the only kinds of groups with exactly 2 or 3 members. (My $x$ is not the $x$ of your Q.)

Comment: "So we aren't "allowed" to use that reasoning (Lagrange)". I wonder why we should solve then this exercise if we don't know Lagrange. This is so basic for dealing with finite groups und their subgroups.

Comment: @DietrichBurde For the course I'm taking, we just simply haven't gotten to the section where Lagrange's Theorem is given. It seems strange to me as well, as I have done some studying beforehand, but who am I to argue with the course outline. I'm sure it's set up this way for a reason.

Comment: Yes, I also won't argue with the course outline. It seems good that you learn about Lagrange now. As for elementary number theory, when you have to solve an exercise about divisors and are "not allowed" to use that every integer is the product of primes. Well - how sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that both $3$-cycles together with the identity give you the subgroup of order $3$. And each of the transpositions together with the identity produce their own subgroup of order $2$. In each of these cases, you can show that adding any other element generates the entire group $G = S_3$:

- If $H < G$ contains at least one of $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ **and** at least one of $\{x, y, z\}$, then $H = G$.
- If $H < G$ contains at least two of $\{x, y, z\}$, then $H = G$.

---

The key concept in all of this is to consider what a set of elements *generates,* meaning all elements that are guaranteed to be in the subgroup as a consequence of closure and inverses. For instance, if your subgroup contains the $3$-cycle $\alpha$, then it **has to** contain $\beta$ since $\beta = \alpha^2$ (also $\beta = \alpha^{-1}$). In symbols, the subgroup *generated by* an element, say $\alpha$, is
$$
\langle \alpha \rangle = \{ \alpha^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}, 
$$
and in this group, it happens that $\alpha^3 = e$, so $\alpha^m = \alpha^n$ if and only if $m \equiv n \pmod{3}$. Hence,
$$
\langle \alpha \rangle = \{ e, \alpha, \alpha^2 \}.
$$
The bulleted claims above can be written more succinctly in the language of generators, e.g. $\langle \alpha, x \rangle = G$, etc.